# Using the algebraic properties of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

[image]
I have the mark scheme for this but I just dont understand how it goes about proving the right side. How should I approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a+b+c=0$ then $c=-(a+b)$, hence
$$b\times c=b\times(-(a+b))=-b\times(a+b)=-(b\times a+b\times b)=-b\times a=a\times b.$$
A similar calculation does the trick for $c\times a$.

Comment: ah I get it, thats a much more intuitive way of looking at it than the mark scheme